# Stopping and starting a Timer in ASP.NET Ajax

Tags: asp.net-ajax

If you have an ASP.NET UpdatePanel and and ASP.NET Timer that trigers theUpdatePanel to refresh, is it posible, in javascript, to stop/pause the timer?

I want to stop the timer when the users mouse is over the updatepanel!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://forums.asp.net/t/1094798.aspx

then just attach a client side event to the updatepanel ala -

http://encosia.com/2007/07/13/easily-refresh-an-updatepanel-using-javascript/ - but change to onmouseover to call them.

Answer (score 11):

The best way is to use enabled property for the timer control

```
timer1.Enabled = false; //For stop the timer

timer1.Enabled = true; // For starting the timer
```

Comment: for some reason, my timer doesn't start again after I set it to false on page load. Any explanation for this?